# Sequential colormaps and pie graph in python

Tags: python, heatmap, pie-chart

Has anyone tried assigning colors to python pie graph using sequential color map? Heatmap packages in python comes with predefined shapes (equal squares) and I would like to show shapes (like rectangles- size will be changed) and colors based on the value

My goal is next:

1) attach to each value of DataFrame color from sequential colormap

2) build pie graph for each column

I tried to play with bar(polar) graph using this code:

```
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0)
for r, bar,ll in zip(radii, bars,labels):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.YlOrRd(r / 10.))
    bar.set_alpha(0.5)
    bar.set_label(ll)
ax.legend()
```

but the color was assigning randomly, not based on value.

it is really easy to do it in Excel using conditioning formatting but could not find anything like this in python

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Questions that are solely about programming are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the site and may be closed.  Programming questions should be migrated to StackOverflow (you can ask the moderators to do this).  We also maintain a list of internet resources for statistics software [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software)

Comment: Thank you - who can I ask about moving to StackOverflow?

Comment: I have already flagged your question, but you can also flag it and ask for it to be migrated (choose the "in need of moderator intervention" option)